# ! You can't use `\unskip' in vertical mode. ... How to get space between lines?

Tags: vertical-alignment, amsart

I searched the error, but I didn't seem to find anyone who actually *wanted* the spacing. Also, this is my first question on Tex Stack Exchange, so let me know if I've formatted anything incorrectly, failed to follow any conventions, etc.

My reduced example code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\begin{document}

\[Some stuff\]

~

\[Some more stuff\]

\end{document}
```

which generates the following error:

```
! You can't use `\unskip' in vertical mode.
\nonbreakingspace ->\unskip 
                            \nobreak \ \ignorespaces 
l.8 ~
```

Comment: You can use `\medskip` or `\bigskip` for example, or `\vspace{2em}`.

Comment: Hin and welcome, please not, that `$$ math $$` is obsolete for a long long time, use `\[ math \]` instead. You also might be interested in the environments provided by `amsmath`, for example `gather` and `gather*`.

Comment: `\leavevmode~` should work. But that's definetly wrong. Post a full example of a proof and let the people here tell you all the things that are wrong. Just to start: `$$..$$` should be `\[..\]`, if there are more than one mathematical enviroment with no text in between, you should use `gather` or `align` (from `mathtools`); and `~` *is a non breaking space*, what's it doing at the first place of a paragraph?

Comment: @Sigur Thanks. If you post that as an answer I'll accept it. Also, can you explain to me why the blank line trick wouldn't work here?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein, it is not necessary to answer. This is a simple solution and there are many posts here about vertical spaces. Thanks.

Comment: @Sigur That was rather curt. As I clearly indicated in the question, when I googled this error I did not find what I needed, so my hope was that by introducing this question, people googling this same issue in the future would be able to find the solution here. Also, you did not answer my follow-up question; why can't I just create a line with no text, and use ~ so that LaTeX recognizes a proper line there?

Comment: Note that the standard definition of `~` would not give this error, you must have redefined it. It always help if you provide a _complete_ document that allows other people to reproduce the problem (although it does not really work as a way to add vertical space) the behaviour at a page break will be awful.

Comment: @Sigur only if we guess what `~` means here: the standard definition starts with `\leavevmode` and doesn't use `\unskip`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It's a lot of code to post and indent by 4 spaces, even after I've reduced the example; is there a way I am supposed to be able to paste it and indent the entire block at once?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein highlight with mouse then use `{}` button on the editor bar or just control-k (but it shouldn't be a _lot_ just a few lines more than you posted originally)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well, it's a matter of narrowing down what particular line redefines ~, as you say, since I have a big header. You helped me figure out what line it is; I'll edit the question accordingly. The problem line was \documentclass[12pt]{amsart}.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein ooh that's a bug you should report it to them:-) (you should _never_ start a line with `~` (which is why the bug has survived 30 years) but still it ought not do that.

Comment: sorry, @David, it's intentional.  `texdoc amsclass` and go to page 50.  it's the first thing there under "miscellaneous", and `\nonbreakingspace`, with the rationale.  (egreg has already explained it in his answer.)  while i agree that it's not intuitive, i venture to say it has saved many hours of copyediting time at ams, since it obliterates random "blanks" at the beginning and ends of lines in text.

Comment: @barbarabeeton read the documentation? what a suggestion:-) but it's still a bug redefining  to add the unskip is fine (and documented) but it ought to start with \leavevmode or test for vmode and give a sensible error so it doesn't give the primitive tex error in the title if used at the start of a paragraph.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `amsart` class redefines `~` to be `\protect\nonbreakingspace` that indeed does `\unskip` and `\ignorespaces`, because it wants to catch cases when users type

```
some ~ word
```

and normalize them as if it were `some~word`.

The correct way for “leaving a blank line” is to say

```
text above

\bigskip

text below
```

With the definition in `amsart`, this makes `~` illegal at the start of a paragraph.

In your case, it seems you're using consecutive math displays, which is wrong for other reasons: you should use `gather*`. Note that `$$...$$` should *never* be used in LaTeX.

```
\begin{gather*}
eq1 \\
eq2 \\[3ex]% some vertical space
eq3
\end{gather*}
```

There are several other alignment environments available. Check `texdoc amsmath`.

Answer (score 5):

The standard definition of `~` will not generate this error

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
...

$$some stuff$$

$$some more stuff$$

~ % want space here to set apart from above

$$yet more stuff$$

...
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

You appear to have a local redefinition of `~` that starts with `\unskip`  which is clearly incorrect but a quick search of my local tex tree didn't suggest a package you could be using that makes such a definition.

Even though the above is error free, the vertical "gap" is not a vertical space it is a horizontal line of a "white paragraph" just consisting of `~` as such it will not behave correctly, neither stretching nor shrinking nor being discarded at a page break.

`$$` is not supported latex syntax, but display math environments should never be used one after the other, whether `$$` or supported environments such as `\begin{equation}`. 
If you use a multline environment you can if needed increase the spacing for example

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
...

\begin{gather*}
some stuff\\
some more stuff\\[1cm]
yet more stuff
\end{gather*}

...
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

i'm largely guessing here, but since you're using `amsart`, ...

from your description, it seems that you want a large gap between two math displays.
that is usually considered inappropriate (see recommendations in [*Mathematics into Type*](http://www.ams.org/arc/styleguide/mit-2.pdf)), but presumably you have a reason.

there is a standard facility for adding space between two lines of a multi-line display.  that is to specify the value of the dimension as an option after the `\\`  separating two lines of such a display.  remember, do *not* leave a space between the backslashes and the
option.  `amsmath` goes to great lengths to recognize spaces in this position, so that
expressions on the "next" line that start with brackets won't get trapped by the default
latex assumption that anything in that location in brackets *must* be an option.

example:

```
\begin{gather*}
  x + y = z \\[12pt]
  abc = def
\end{gather*}
```

Comment: Barbara, if I have two lines of math that are related and then another line which starts a new idea, is it inappropriate to want an extra gap in between to set them apart?

Comment: @DustanLevenstein -- it would probably be more appropriate to insert a small bit of descriptive text, to inform the reader about what is going on.

Comment: I suppose I could do that. This particular example is live-tex'd from a lecture, so perhaps some deviance from the standards is to be expected in the translation between different media.